# Eloquent sync() belongsToMany with pivot and nested children

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I would like to solve this issue. I got an json like that:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "One",
    "parent": {},
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "One One",
        "parent": {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "One"
        },
        "children": [],
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "One Two",
        "parent": {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "One"
        },
        "children": [],
        "value": 2
      }
    ],
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Three",
    "value": 3
  }
]
```

As you can see, each item can have a child, which can also have a child, which can also have a child and so on. It's nested.

Now I'd like to save these `items` and each child in a `belongsToMany` relation with pivot (in this case: `value`).  If I want to use `sync()`, I would have to prepare all my items in my controller:

```
 <?php

/*Save $items*/
$items
    = collect($request->input('data.items'))->mapWithKeys(function (
    $item
) {

    if (array_key_exists('value', $item)) {
        $value = $item['value'];
    } else {
        $value = null;
    }

    return [
        $item['id'] => compact('value'),
    ];
});

$user->items()->sync($items);
```

But this does not go recursively through all children. I thought about something like that:

```
/*Save items*/
$items
    = collect($request->input('data.items'))->mapWithKeys(function (
    $item
) {
    $traverse = function ($item) use (&$traverse) {
        if (array_key_exists('value', $item)) {
            $value = $item['value'];
        } else {
            $value = null;
        }

        foreach ($item['children'] as $child) {
            $child = $traverse($child);
        }

        $children = ($item['children']);

        return [
            $item['id'] => compact('value', 'children'),
        ];
    };

    $item = $traverse($item);
```

But this does not work out.

What I want as a result:

- Save every `item` as a `belongsToMany` relation for the `user` with pivot `value`
- Save all `children` recursively with pivot `value`

Comment: what you want yo have as a result? please write about that to be more easy readable for those who will help ;)

Comment: Sorry, I added the missing information,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I want to mention that your data is JSON actually, not an array. So here I write some code, where you can see that I decoded and got an array from that (start from loop() function).

As I understand, you want to collect all items values into 1 array, which will be used for saving all relations for 1 user. So with this you can have that output array (see the bottom of loop() function).

```
protected $result = [];

protected function deepDiveIntoNextLevel(array $array) {
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $this->result[] = $item['value'];
        if(!empty($item['children'])) {
            $this->deepDiveIntoNextLevel($item['children']);
        }
    }
}

public function loop()
{
    $json_array = '[
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "One",
        "parent": {},
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "One One",
            "parent": {
              "id": 2,
              "title": "One"
            },
            "children": [],
            "value": 1
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "One Two",
            "parent": {
              "id": 2,
              "title": "One"
            },
            "children": [],
            "value": 2
          }
        ],
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Three",
        "value": 3
      }
    ]';
    $initial_array = json_decode($json_array, true);

    $this->deepDiveIntoNextLevel($initial_array);
    $result = $this->result;
    // As output you may get an array, where you can have duplicates
    sort($result);
    // Or it can be not ordered
    $relations_ids_odered = array_unique($result);
}
```